# How to flush one cold observable as opposed to all observables in the test?

Tags: unit-testing, rxjs6, jasmine-marbles

`getTestScheduler().flush()` flushes all the observables in the test. Is there a way to granularly flush observables?

e.g. `cold('--x', {x: {}}).flush()`

Comment: Please provide codepen or at least testing code+tests list. Never did this but you can try to create a few testScheduler instances and operate then independantly

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After @Alexander Poshtaruk commented, I took a look at the source code of `jasmine-marbles`.

Unfortunately, there is no way to make `jasmine-marbles` flush observables independently, as they all depend on the same `TestScheduler` instance.

`jasmine-marbles` inits and resets the `TestScheduler` instance automatically before and after every spec:

```
jasmine.getEnv().beforeEach(() => initTestScheduler());
jasmine.getEnv().afterEach(() => {
    getTestScheduler().flush();
    resetTestScheduler();
});
```

You can simply manually create multiple `TestScheduler` instances for each groups of observables you wish to flush.